# How to query parent with properties of children and grandchildren in local data in EF Core 1.1?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

While importing data from legacy systems to new system I need to find items with their names and properties instead of IDs. Also the whole imported set should be saved only if everything validates. So I can't do saves in between processing different entities.

I used to have this query working in EF6:

```
      MetaAttribute fromAttribute =
                    db.Attributes
                    .Single(a =>
                        (a.Concept.Name.Equals(entityName)) &&
                        (a.Concept.System.Code.Equals(defaultSystem.Code)) &&
                        (a.Name.Equals(attributeName)))
                ??   db.Attributes.Local.Single(a => (a.Concept.Name == entityName) && (a.Concept.System.Code == defaultSystem.Code) && (a.Name == attributeName));
```

If I try to run this with Entity Framework Core 1.1 I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException occurred   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=Field
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[MetaUI.Models.MetaAttribute,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.MetaConcept]].Inner'
>   is not defined for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Project.Models.MetaAttribute,Project.Models.MetaConcept]'
>   Source=System.Linq.Expressions   StackTrace:
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Field(Expression expression, FieldInfo field)   InnerException:

What does this error mean and what is the best practice for this kind of queries with EF 1.1?

Whole model is very complex, but here are simplified versions of the relevant classes.
Addition (entity classes and configuration):

```
 public class MetaAttribute : MetaBase, IValidatableObject
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AttributeID { get; set; }


        [MaxLength(350)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ConceptID")]
        [JsonIgnore]

        public MetaConcept Concept { get; set; }
        public int? ConceptID { get; set; }
}

 public class MetaConcept : MetaBase
    {        
        [Key]
        public int ConceptID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ConceptVersionID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public MetaConcept FromConcept { get; set; }

        public int? SystemID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SystemID")]
        public MetaSystem System { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MetaAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }

        public MetaConcept()
        {
            Attributes = new Collection<MetaAttribute>();

        }
    }   

  public class MetaSystem : MetaBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int SystemID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(400)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }   

 public abstract class MetaBase
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string LastChangedBy { get; set; }


    }
```

Configuration:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MetaAttribute>()
                .Property(b => b.AttributeID)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        modelBuilder.Entity<MetaSystem>()
           .HasAlternateKey(c => c.Code);
```

Comment: Which part produces the exception - `db.Attributes.Local....`?

Comment: It produces the exception even without the local part.

Comment: Can you post the model (entity classes + configuration if present)?

Comment: @IvanStoev Updated the question to include more code

Comment: Thank you. I've applied your model to a test EF Core database, but cannot reproduce the exact exception. I'm getting `InvalidOperationException` with message "Sequence contains no elements" which is expected from such code. Once I change `Single` to `SingleOrDefault` (or `FirstOrDefault`), it executes w/o problem. EF Core 1.1.0, SqlServer db if that matters. But of course I have no data (the tables are empty).

Comment: Can you try creating at least one of each entity. I've tested this some more and it seems to crash on the grand children part: (a.Concept.System.Code.Equals(defaultSystem.Code))

Comment: Done, but still can't reproduce. I've assumed `defaultSystem` variable is of type `MetaSystem`, correct?

Comment: Unbelievable, I am so shamed. This issue seems to be due overdebugging in Visual Studio. Just ignoring the exception helped. Thank you anyway for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: No problem, glad that the issue is resolved :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for me was to exclude this exception from debugger. So I was overdebugging with Visual Studio.